# How to make this path finding C++ code into dynamic so that agent can search the path on its own

Tags: visual-c++

How to make this path finding C++ code into dynamic so that agent can search the path on its own (from one corner of grid to another corner) but agent can't see unless and until move to the grid.  I am new for C++ and try to made this little program but it seems to be static I need help so that I can change it into dynamic or may be agent can do the path search on its own not by assigning the path, so far I made 5 different path, because agent can choose as many path as he want but the path length should be 6 and can move only in up or right direction. Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

```
 #include <iostream> 
#include <ctime> 
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

using namespace std;
using namespace System;
using namespace System::IO;

/*int Grid[ 4 ][ 4 ] = 
{
    { 29, 8, 11, 9 },
    { 22, 24, 3, 15 },
    { 24, 26, 5, 6 },
    { 33, 10, 32, 21}
};
int Grid[ 4 ][ 4 ] = 
    {
    { 0, 0, -5, 0.0 },
    { -1, 0, 2, 2 },
    { 2, 0, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 2, 0, -1}
    };
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++   
    */
int g[16] = {33,10,32,21,24,26,5,6,22,24,3,15,29,8,11,9};
int r[16] = {0,2,0,-1,2,0,0,0,-1,0,2,2,0,0,-5,0};


#define SPACE "[   ]" 

bool Finished( false );
int m[4];
//int E = 6;
int E, E1, E2, E3;


void printmatrix(char arg[], int length)
{

    for (int j = length; j >= 0; j=-4)
    {
    cout <<"\n" << arg[j] << "\n ";

    }   
    //}
}
void FindNextPos()
{       std::cout<<"\n"<<"Search Path 1"<<"\n";
    for (int c= 1; c < 5; c++)
        {   if(r[c] != r[3])
                {   
                    m[c] = 1;
                    E = E + r[c] - 1;


//std::cout<<"(ID,R,E)"<<"-->"<<"("<<g[c]<<","<<r[c]<<","<<E <<")"<<m[c]<< std::endl;

                    //system("pause");
                }
    else 
                {
                Finished = true;
std::cout<<"(ID,R,E)"<<"-->"<<"("<<g[c]<<","<<r[c]<<","<<E <<")"<<m[c]<< std::endl;
                }
    }

        for (int c= 7; c <= 16; c= c+ 4)
                {   
                    if(r[c] != r[16]){
                    m[c] = 2;
                    E = E + r[c] - 1;
    //std::cout<<"(ID,R,E)"<<"-->"<<"("<<g[c]<<","<<r[c]<<","<<E <<")"<< std::endl;

                    //system("pause");
                }
    else 
                {
                //m[c] = 2;
                Finished = true;
    std::cout<<"(ID,R,E)"<<"-->"<<"("<<g[c]<<","<<r[c]<<","<<E <<")"<< std::endl;
                }
}
        }

//int E1 = 6;
void nextpos1(){ 

    std::cout<<"\n"<<"Search Path 2"<<"\n";
for (int c= 0; c < 3; c++)
        {   if(r[c] != r[3])
                {   
                    m[c] = 3;
                    E1 = E1 + r[c] - 1;
    std::cout<<"(ID,R,E)"<<"-->"<<"("<<g[c]<<","<<r[c]<<","<<E1 <<")"<< std::endl;
                    //system("pause");
                }
    else 
                {
                Finished = true;
std::cout<<"(ID,R,E)"<<"-->"<<"("<<g[c]<<","<<r[c]<<","<<E1 <<")"<< std::endl;
                }
    }

        for (int c= 6; c < 15; c= c + 4)
                {   
                    if(r[c] != r[16]){
                    m[c] = 4;
                    E1 = E1 + r[c] - 1;

std::cout<<"(ID,R,E)"<<"-->"<<"("<<g[c]<<","<<r[c]<<","<<E1 <<")"<< std::endl;
                    //system("pause");
                }
    else 
                {
                        m[c] = 4;
                Finished = true;
std::cout<<"(ID,C,E)"<<"-->"<<"("<<g[c]<<","<<r[c]<<","<<E1 + r[c] - 1 <<")"<< std::endl;
                }
        }
        for (int c= 15; c < 16; ++c)
                {   
                    if(r[c] != 0){
                    m[c] = 5;
                    E1 = E1 + r[c] - 1;

std::cout<<"(ID,R,E)"<<"-->"<<"("<<g[c]<<","<<r[c]<<","<<E1 <<")"<< std::endl;
                    //system("pause");
                }
    else 
                {
                        m[c] = 5;
                Finished = true;
std::cout<<"(ID,R,E)"<<"-->"<<"("<<g[c]<<","<<r[c]<<","<<E1 <<")"<< std::endl;
std::cout << "\n"<<"finish-->" << r[c] << "\t" <<"E1-->"<< E1 <<"\n" ;
                }
        }
}
    //int E2 = 6;
void nextpos2(){ 
        std::cout<<"\n"<<"Search Path 3"<<"\n";
for (int c= 0; c < 2; c++)
        {   if(r[c] != r[3])
                {   
                    m[c] = 6;
                    E2 = E2 + r[c] - 1;

std::cout<<"(ID,R,E)"<<"-->"<<"("<<g[c]<<","<<r[c]<<","<<E2 <<")"<< std::endl;
                    //system("pause");
                }
    else 
                {
                Finished = true;
std::cout<<"(ID,R,E)"<<"-->"<<"("<<g[c]<<","<<r[c]<<","<<E2 <<")"<< std::endl;
                }
    }

        for (int c= 1; c < 12; c= c + 4)
                {   
                    if(r[c] != r[14]){
                    m[c] = 7;
                    E2 = E2 + r[c] - 1;

std::cout<<"(ID,R,E)"<<"-->"<<"("<<g[c]<<","<<r[c]<<","<<E2 <<")"<< std::endl;
                    //system("pause");
                }
    else 
                {
                        //m[c] = 7;
                Finished = true;
std::cout<<"(C,E)"<<"-->"<<"("<<r[c]<<","<<E2 + r[c] - 1 <<")"<< std::endl;
                }
        }
        for (int c= 13; c < 16; ++c)
                {   m[c] = 8;
                    if(r[c] != r[16]){

                    E2 = E2 + r[c] - 1;

std::cout<<"(ID,R,E)"<<"-->"<<"("<<g[c]<<","<<r[c]<<","<<E2 <<")"<< std::endl;
                    //system("pause");
                }
    else 
                {
                    //  m[c] = 8;
                Finished = true;
std::cout<<"(ID,R,E)"<<"-->"<<"("<<g[c]<<","<<r[c]<<","<<E2 <<")"<< std::endl;
std::cout << "\n"<<"finish-->" << r[c] << "\t" <<"E-->"<< E1 <<"\n" ;
                }
        }
}   

//int E3 = 6;
void nextpos3(){ 

    std::cout<<"\n"<<"Search Path 4"<<"\n";
for (int c= 0; c <= 12; c= c+ 4)
    //for (int c= 4; c <= 12; c= c+ 4)
        {   if(r[c] != r[12])
                {   
                    m[c] = 11;
                    E3 = E3 + r[c] - 1;
                    std::cout<<"\n";
std::cout<<"(ID,R,E)"<<"-->"<<"("<<g[c]<<","<<r[c]<<","<<E3 <<")"<< std::endl;
                    //system("pause");
                }
    else 
                {
                m[c] = 11;
                Finished = true;
std::cout<<"(ID,R,E)"<<"-->"<<"("<<g[c]<<","<<r[c]<<","<<E3 + r[c] - 1 <<")"<< std::endl;
                }
    }
    E3 = E3 -1;
        for (int c= 13; c < 16; c++)
                {   
                    if(r[c] != r[15]){
                    m[c] = 12;
                    E3 = E3 + r[c] - 1;

std::cout<<"(ID,R,E)"<<"-->"<<"("<<g[c]<<","<<r[c]<<","<<E3 <<")"<< std::endl;
                    //system("pause");
                }
    else 
                {
                        m[c] = 12;
                        Finished = true;
                        std::cout<<"(ID,R,E)"<<"-->"<<"("<<g[c]<<","<<r[c]<<","<<E3 + r[c] - 1 <<")"<< std::endl;
                }
        }

}   

void nextpos4(){ 
    int E4 = 6;
    std::cout<<"\n"<<"Search Path 5"<<"\n";
for (int c= 4; c <= 8; c= c+ 4)
    //for (int c= 4; c <= 12; c= c+ 4)
        {   if(r[c] != r[8])
                {   cout<<E4;
                    m[c] = 13;
                    E4 = E4 + r[c] - 1;
                    std::cout<<"\n";
                    std::cout<<"(ID,R,E)"<<"-->"<<"("<<g[c]<<","<<r[c]<<","<<E4 <<")"<< std::endl;
                    //system("pause");
                }
    else 
                {
                m[c] = 13;
                Finished = true;
std::cout<<"(ID,R,E)"<<"-->"<<"("<<g[c]<<","<<r[c]<<","<<E4 + r[c] - 1 <<")"<< std::endl;
                }
    }
    E4 = E4 -1;
        for (int c= 9; c < 12; c++)
                {   
                    if(r[c] != r[11]){
                    m[c] = 14;
                    E4 = E4 + r[c] - 1;

std::cout<<"(ID,R,E)"<<"-->"<<"("<<g[c]<<","<<r[c]<<","<<E4 <<")"<< std::endl;
                    //system("pause");
                }
            else 
                {
                        m[c] = 14;
                        Finished = true;
std::cout<<"(ID,R,E)"<<"-->"<<"("<<g[c]<<","<<r[c]<<","<<E3 + r[c] - 1 <<")"<< std::endl;
                }
        }
        for (int c= 11; c < 16; c = c + 4)
                {   
                    if(r[c] != r[15]){
                    //m[c] = 15;
                    E4 = E4 + r[c] - 1;

std::cout<<"(ID,R,E)"<<"-->"<<"("<<g[c]<<","<<r[c]<<","<<E4 <<")"<< std::endl;
                    //system("pause");
                }
            else 
                {
                        m[c] = 15;
                        Finished = true;
std::cout<<"(ID,R,E)"<<"-->"<<"("<<g[c]<<","<<r[c]<<","<<E4 + r[c] - 1 <<")"<< std::endl;
                }
        }

}   
void PrintRoute( void )
{//std::cout << "Start Node : " << g[0]<<"\t" <<"Finish Node : " << g[15] <<"\n";

std::cout << "\n"<< "Route 1 : "<<"\n";
  for (int c= 1; c < 14; c++)
  {  
        if( m[c] == 1)
            std::cout<< "[r]-->"<<"\t";
            else if (m[c] == 2)
                 std::cout<< "[u]-->"<<"\t";
                    else 
                     std::cout <<"";
   }
    std::cout << "\n";   
}

void PrintRoute1( void )
{//std::cout << "\n"<< "Start Node : " << g[0]<<"\t" << "Finish Node : " << g[15]<<"\n";
std::cout << "\n"<< "Route 2 : "<<"\n";
  for (int c= 1; c < 16; c++)
  {
        if( m[c] == 3 )
            std::cout<< "[r]-->"<<"\t";
            else if (m[c] == 4 )
                 std::cout<< "[u]-->"<<"\t";
            else if (m[c] == 5)
                std::cout<<"[r]-->"<<"\t";
                else 
                     std::cout <<"";
   }

    std::cout << "\n";

}

void PrintRoute2( void )
{//std::cout << "\n"<< "Start Node : " << g[0] <<"\t"<< "Finish Node : " << g[15]<<"\n";
std::cout << "\n"<< "Route 3: "<<"\n";
  for (int c= 0; c < 15; c++)
  {
        if( m[c] == 6 || m[c] == 8 )
            std::cout<< "[r]-->"<<"\t";
            else if (m[c] == 7 )
                 std::cout<< "[u]-->"<<"\t";
            //else if (m[c] == 8)
            //  std::cout<<"[r]"<<"\t";
                else 
                     std::cout <<"";
   }

    std::cout << "\n";
    }

void PrintRoute3( void )
{//std::cout << "Start Node : " << g[0] <<"\t"<< "Finish Node : " << g[15]<<"\n";

std::cout << "\n"<< "Route 4 : "<<"\n";
  for (int c = 0; c <= 15; c++)
  {  
        if( m[c] == 11)
            std::cout<< "[u]-->"<<"\t";
            else if (m[c] == 12)
                 std::cout<< "[r]-->"<<"\t";
                    else 
                     std::cout <<"";
   }
    std::cout << "\n";   
}
void PrintRoute4( void )
{//std::cout << "\n"<< "Start Node : " << g[0]<<"\t" << "Finish Node : " << g[15]<<"\n";
std::cout << "\n"<< "Route 2 : "<<"\n";
  for (int c= 1; c < 16; c++)
  {
        if( m[c] == 13 )
            std::cout<< "[u]-->"<<"\t";
            else if (m[c] == 14 )
                 std::cout<< "[r]-->"<<"\t";
            else if (m[c] == 15)
                std::cout<<"[u]-->"<<"\t";
                else 
                     std::cout <<"";
   }
}

int main( )

{   int E,E1,E2,E3;

    int a, b;
int m[4][4];
ifstream in;
char state1[] = {'d','p','S','1','3'};
printmatrix(state1, 4);
cout<<"open test file : press";
 in.open("C:/Users /test.txt");
        if (!in) {
                cout << "Cannot open file.\n";
                    system("pause");
                return 0;
                 }

     for (b = 1; b <= 4; b++) {cout << "\n";
            for (a = 1; a <= 4; a++) {
                  in >> m[a][b]; 

                 cout <<"\t" << "["<<m[a][b] <<"]" ; 
                                  }
                cout << "\n";
                //
             } 
            in.close();
                std::cout << "\n";  
int mt[6][6];
     cout<<"open training file : press";

             ifstream i;

             i.open("C:/Users/training.txt");
                if (!i) {
                    cout << "Cannot open file.\n";
                    return 0;
                 }
                cout << "\n";

                for (b = 1; b <= 6; b++) {cout << "\n";
                    for (a = 1; a <= 6; a++) {
                             i >> mt[a][b]; 
                             cout <<"\t" << "["<<mt[a][b] <<"]" ; 
                                  }
                        cout << "\n";
                         } 
            i.close();
                std::cout << "\n";  


    system("pause");

    int F = E = E1 = E2= E3;
    std::cout<< "Enter Energy E";
    //std::cin>>E >> E1 >> E2 >> E3 >>E4;
    std::cin>>F;
    std::cout << "Start Node : " << g[0] <<"\t"<< "Finish Node : " << g[15]<<"\n";
    while( !Finished )
        FindNextPos();
        PrintRoute( );
        nextpos1();
        PrintRoute1();
        nextpos2();
        PrintRoute2();
        nextpos3();
        PrintRoute3();
        nextpos4();
        PrintRoute4();
        std::cin.get( );
        system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need some kind of [**path finding algorithm**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DINCL5cd_w0&feature=related).

The A* ("A-Star") algorithm is probably a good place to start. [**This page**](https://web.archive.org/web/20171022224528/http://www.policyalmanac.org:80/games/aStarTutorial.htm) does a decent job of explaining it. If A* seems to complicated, you may want to try Dijkstra's algorithm first. Dijkstra's algorithm is the same as A*, but without the heuristic(estimated cost to goal).